# Focus for UICollectionViewCells on tvOS

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, tvos

I'm new to tvOS. I have created UICollectionView using a XIB file in Objective-C. How can I focus UICollectionViewCell?

I have a label and an image view in the cell, and I want to focus both the label and the image view.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`UICollectionViewCell` are not focus appearance by default, but you can achive this by adding one yourself.

```
- (void)didUpdateFocusInContext:(UIFocusUpdateContext *)context withAnimationCoordinator:(UIFocusAnimationCoordinator *)coordinator
{
    if (self.focused)
    {
        // Apply focused appearence,
        // e.g scale both of them using transform or apply background color 
    }
    else
    {
       // Apply normal appearance
    }
}
```

OR

If you just want to focus `ImageView` like scaling it up when collection view cell get focus you can do like this in `awakeFromNib` method

```
self.imageView.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused = YES;
self.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

Comment: Should be 'clipsToBounds' ('s' is missing).

Comment: @IdanMoshe nicely spotted. it's generally fine to just go ahead and edit very minor typos like that.

Answer (score 4):

Add this in custom class of `collectionview`:

```
override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) { 
 if (self.focused) {
   collectionView.image.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused = true
 } else {
   collectionView.image.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused = false
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add below methods to your collectionview cell.It will show title of focussed cell only giving complete look and feel of focus.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // These properties are also exposed in Interface Builder.
        imageView.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused = true
        imageView.clipsToBounds = false

        title.alpha = 0.0
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionReusableView

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        // Reset the label's alpha value so it's initially hidden.
        title.alpha = 0.0
    }

    // MARK: UIFocusEnvironment

    override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
        /*
         Update the label's alpha value using the `UIFocusAnimationCoordinator`.
         This will ensure all animations run alongside each other when the focus
         changes.
         */
        coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({
            if self.focused {
                self.title.alpha = 1.0
            }
            else {
                self.title.alpha = 0.0
            }
            }, completion: nil)
    }
```